# Conditional formatting for entire Column based on another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to have a cell highlighted green if the next cell is greater than the current cell. This formatting should apply for an entire column.

E.g. if `A2 > B2` then `A2` should become green. If `A3 > B3` then `A3` should become green, and so on.

Note: I want to not have this done by individual formatting, but by a general rule.

Comment: Hey Kavin, I noticed this is your first question: Welcome to StackOverflow! I did some edits to your question because I had problems understanding it. I highly recommend you check out our guide [How do I ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Conditional formatting`, add new rule with type `Use a formula...`, add formula `=$A1>$B1`, into `Applies to` add range `=$A:$A`. That's all.

[image]